# subscription returned by AppState.addEventListener() is void

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

when i try to remove the eventListener like in the React native documentation for AppState: https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate, I either get an error that there is no such function remove() on undefined since AppState.addEventListener() returns void or the eventListener is just not removed.

here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextAppState: any) => {
      // some stuff 
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

If anyone has an idea on that matter, i would be very grateful, thank you !

I found someone on github with the same issue I believe:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found the answer this due to the fact that im on react-native 0.64 and not 0.67

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I added another answer above with more detail since I also didn't find this answer had enough detail. :-P

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you're using a version of react-native prior to 0.65. Starting with 0.65, `AppState.removeEventListener` is deprecated in favor of using `remove` in the subscription returned by `addEventListener.

[These](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.64/appstate#removeeventlistener) are the 0.64 docs for `removeEventListener`. And [these](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.65/appstate#removeeventlistener) are the corresponding 0.65 docs that add the deprecation notice.